# Syntax error, unexpected T_SL

Tags: mime, php

I'm fairly new to php and I'm using a script that creates a function called the "mime_mailer" which essentially allows me to use PHP to send emails that are able to be designed with CSS instead of being merely plain text.

Yet, in my registration script, I try to write some code that sends a CSS email, but I get an error saying that there's a syntax error. Could someone please fill me in on this?

```
            $subject = "Your Red-line Account";
    $css     = "body{ color: #090127; background-color: #f0f0f0; }"; 
    $to     =   $usercheck;

    //Message
    $message =<<<END 
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>
                            Red-line
                        </title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>
                            Hi $first_name, 
                        </p> 

                        <p>
                            Your Red-line account is almost complete. To finish, go to <a href='www.thered-line.com'>The Red-line</a> and enter your eight digit confirmation code.
                        </p> 

                        <p>
                            Your confirmation code is: <b>$code</b>
                        </p> 

                        <p>
                            Sincerely,
                        </p> <br />

                        <p>
                            The Red-line Operator
                        </p> 
                    </body>
                </html>
            END;

                    //  To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers    =   'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers    .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

                    //  Additional headers
        $headers    .=  "From: The Red-line <messages@theredline.com>\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "To: $first_name $last_name <$usercheck>\r\n";

                    //  Mail it
        require_once("function_mime_mailer.php");


        mime_mailer($to, $subject, $message, $headers, NULL, $css); 
}
```

Here is the code for the "function_mime_mailer.php" file.

```
  if(basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) send_404(); // stop http access           to         this file

 function mime_mailer($to, $subject, $message, $headers = NULL, $attachments = NULL, $css = NULL)
 {
       if(!preg_match('/^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-        z]{2,6})$/', $to)) return FALSE;
if(preg_match('/<(html|head|body|div|a|h|p|table|br|img|b|hr|ol|ul|span|pre|i|form)[^>]*[^>]*>/i', $message)) $html = TRUE;

 if(stristr($message, '<body')) $message = stristr($message, '<body');
     $message = delete_local_links($message);
 if(empty($headers)){
     $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 }else{
     $headers.= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 }
 if(empty($html)){
     $result = plain_text($message);
 }elseif(isset($html) and $html == TRUE){
     if(!isset($css)) $css = NULL;
     if(preg_match('/<img[^>]+>/i', $message)){
       $result = multipart_related($message, $css);
   }else{
       $result = multipart_alternative($message, $css);
   }
 }
 $result['message'] = delete_non_cid_images($result['message']);
 if(!empty($attachments)){
   $parts = attachments($attachments);
   array_unshift($parts, implode('', $result));
   $result = multipart_mixed($parts);
 }
$headers = $headers.$result['headers'];
//print '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($headers.$result['message']).'</pre>';exit;
if(mail($to, $subject, $result['message'], $headers)) return TRUE;
return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: Post the error message indicating line number and define that line number in posted code

Comment: The error is in the registration script. It's in the 6th line. The line where the $message variable is defined. Where the <<<END is...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [List of Parser tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php).

`T_SL` references to `<<`.

You should not use tabs or spaces before you use `END;`. Have a look at [this huge warning](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: I switched <<<END to <<END and got rid of the tabs and spaces before I used END and the same error message still displays.

Comment: @Lance: You should change `<<END` back to `<<<END`. You should only remove the tabs and spaces on the same line as `END;`.

Answer (score 25):

Just had the same problem.

Turned out to be content on the same line as my opening HERDEOC

wrong example

```
echo <<<HEREDOC code started on this line
HEREDOC;
```

correct example

```
echo <<<HEREDOC
code should have started on this line
HEREDOC;
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even a space character (which may be hidden in your editor) can cause this problem. _That's_ a brain thumper until you find it.

Comment: Regarding this comment by @JakeParis, I had exactly the same issue, and I have to say in praise of PHPStorm that it _was_ showing me a tiny red squiggly line after the HEREDOC word, indicating the problem...

Answer (score 6):

A side note, but might well help someone: a bad git merge can cause this.  Consider:

```
function foo
    <<<<<<< HEAD
    $bar = 1;
    <<<<<<<  e0f2213bc34d43ef
    $bar = 2;
```

The PHP parser would produce the same error.

Source:  just got bit by this ;)

Comment: Thank you , it is the case with me, but how to solve it? i don't know which file contsin the error

Comment: I'm sorry Shireef that I've not gotten back on this ... career hop at the start of 2020 and a crazy busy time since has kept me away from Stack for the most part.  If you have a UNIX-like system, I'd suggest using `grep` or find piped to grep ....

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  BUT, I couldn't actually see these << characters using Visual Studio.  Do you know why this is?  Thank you!

Comment: Adam, I don't know why you can't see them in VS, but it wouldn't be lying to say that Microsoft has been known to hide things from users that it thinks they might not want to see, or understand.

Answer (score 5):

It had the same exact same issue but mine was because I had whitespace at the end of my heredoc on the top line:

```
$var = <<< HTML(whitespaces here caused the error)
stuff in here
```

HTML;

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/_syntax_error_unexpected_T_SL_in_PHP_Solution-2109-articles

Answer (score 1):

What version of php are you using?
The nowdoc syntax is only valid since PHP 5.3.0.
See the manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: I've recently (in 2017!) hit this error, and this was the cause. My web hosting company are still using PHP 5.2.9 (unsupported since 2014 I think) and it throws this error for a nowdoc.

Remember to check your webhost's PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in function_mime_mailer.php:

```
if(empty($headers)){
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
}else{
   $headers.= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
}
```

should be

```
if(empty($headers)){
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
}else{
   $headers.= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
}
```

also, if you include the MIME-Version header, then the function will include it once more - effectively having two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to needless spaces/tabs in code...

Ran into this after using get merge *feature/branchname*. We use Prettier as formatter, so after accepting both changes - saving the file, fixed the problem.