# PHP parsed error : unexpected '<<' (echo <<<_EOT)

Tags: php, echo

I tried to use `echo <<<` syntax on my website, but it said parse error.

```
<?php
echo <<<_EOT 
<h1>Welcome to www.panthers.zone, TIS community.</h1> 
<br><br> <h5>We are still building our website, Any interest about
<i>The Independent School</i> see: 
</h5> <a href='www.theindependentschool.com'>   
www.theindependentschool.com </a><br><br> Hope you have a good day! --- TIS Web Development club 
_EOT;

?>
```

I've tried many search the solution online but it doesn't appears to be the same problem.

Here is the error log:

> 2017/07/09 22:32:51 [error] 5439#0: *17 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in /var/local/www/front/index.php on line 3" while reading response header from upstream, client: 13.59.195.100, server: panthers.zone, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock:", host: "panthers.zone"

Comment: By the way, it works all right in the php-storm.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that, here is the code:

Comment: <?php

echo <<<_EOT

<h1>Welcome to www.panthers.zone, TIS community.</h1>
<br><br>
<h5>We are still building our website, Any interest about
<i>The Independent School</i> see: </h5>
<a href='www.theindependentschool.com'> www.theindependentschool.com
</a><br><br>
Hope you have a good day! --- TIS Web Development club

_EOT;

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error, unexpected T\_SL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416437/syntax-error-unexpected-t-sl)

Comment: @YiLinLiu Post the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @Deadooshka The error there was indenting the end token, but he isn't doing that in his code.

Comment: @YiLinLiu See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to embed code in posts properly.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much!

Comment: `<<<_EOT ` with extra space may causing that

Comment: @Deadooshka I've tried to delete the space before it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the code. Never use a screenshot to show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

echo <<<_EOT
<h1>Welcome to www.panthers.zone, TIS community.</h1> 
<br/><br/> 
<h5>We are still building our website, Any interest about 
<i>The Independent School</i> see: </h5> 
<a href='www.theindependentschool.com'> www.theindependentschool.com </a>
<br/><br/> 
Hope you have a good day! --- TIS Web Development club 
_EOT;

?>
```

dont give extra space after tag ,use this it should work properly, and why do you want to use it ,cant you use simple php tags

Comment: I am testing this because I have been using a lot of its properties to forge html documents on the server end.

Answer (score -1):

It appears as if you are using the PHP echo function incorrectly.

This is the best place to go to understand how to use it correctly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

However, from what I can see in your screenshot - you are not using any php variables hence you do not need the php tags.

Comment: echo <<<END
This uses the "here document" syntax to output
multiple lines with $variable interpolation. Note
that the here document terminator must appear on a
line with just a semicolon. no extra whitespace!
END;

Comment: Yes this is correct. However I would stay away from this syntax and stick to 

echo "This spans
multiple lines. The newlines will be
output as well";

This syntax is a lot easier to work with in PHP